# How to view text options within a dropdown menu

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, drop-down-menu, webdriver

The HTML of the select list looks like:

```html
<select name="date_range_month_start" id="date_range_month_start" data-width="109px" data-search="true" style="width: 109px; display: none;">
                    <option value="0">January</option>
                    <option value="9">October</option>
                    <option value="10" selected="selected">November</option>
                    <option value="11">December</option>
                 </select>

<div class="chosen-container chosen-container-single chosen-container-single-nosearch" style="width: 109px;" title="" id="date_range_month_start_chosen">
        <a class="chosen-single" tabindex="-1">
            <span>January</span>
                    <div><b></b>
                    </div>
                  </a>
    <div class="chosen-drop">...</div>
    </div>
```

However when I run:

```
month = driver.find_element_by_id('date_range_month_start_chosen')
month.click() ## make dropdown list visible in browser
mySelect = Select(driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#date_range_month_start"))
print([o.text for o in mySelect.options])
```

It prints: 
`['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']`
I've tried a few other things as well but so far have been entirely unsuccessful at printing what the text values in this drop down menu.

Comment: Can you please fix the formatting? I did this for you, but you seem to have reverted it when you added the extra months (which isn't necessary for a minimal verifiable example by the way)

Comment: Please include the element that has the id `date_range_month_start_chosen`, including its relevant side-effects.

Comment: The problem is that the `SELECT` is not visible, at least not in the HTML you pasted. You will need to find how to make it visible. Clicking on the invisible element is not going to make it visible. You don't need to open the dropdown to access it's options.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of points here:

1. Use the `Select` Class to work with the `select` and `options` tags.
2. We should try to select an `option` only through `Select` type of object.
3. Here is the code block for your reference :

   ```
   selectmonth = Select(driver.find_element_by_id('date_range_month_start'))
   for option in selectmonth.options:
       print(option.text)
   ```

### Update

If you face a `ElementNotVisibleException` due to `style="width: 109px; display: none;` use this block of code:

```
element = driver.find_element_by_id('date_range_month_start')   
driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].removeAttribute('style');", element)
selectmonth = Select(driver.find_element_by_id('date_range_month_start'))
for option in selectmonth.options:
    print(option.text)
```

Comment: As DebanjanB point out, your dropdown not implement by select tag, it maybe implement by some plugin, like jQuery drop down plugin, for such drop down is to simulator the UI and behaviour like select tag implemented dropdown did.   For the Select class it can only worked on select tag implemented dropdown. So you shouldn't use Select class at here.

Comment: @yong This is a unusual case of `<select>` tag being disabled. So the exact solution will come out depending on the error we observe by following the generalized solution i.e. trying to select an option through Select type of object.

Comment: The correct step to choose option from such simulator dropdown, first click on the dropdown, to make all options display out, then find the option and click on it. (don't find the option from child nodes of select node, the select node is not visible,  there should be another DOM node to display all options, find out that DOM node, and you will get how to locator the option you want to choose)

Answer (score 0):

Selenium does that when an element is not visible on the screen.

You have `display: none` in your `style` tag. I think you'll find that if you remove it, then you will see what you expect.

I think this is because selenium is built to emulate user behaviour - and a user can not read text that is not shown.

Comment: I've tried running this after using `click()` on the drop down menu so it has become visible to the user, but still the same result.

Comment: That's important to know. Please add this to your question so it can be considered.